# EIntOverflow on Delphi

Tags: delphi

following code triggers an `EIntOverflow` exception.
I can not debug it because that happens on a user PC, not mine.

```
var

  dwread, iBytesPerMFTRecord : cardinal;

  pc : PChar;

begin

////
// some code here
////

Readfile(hDevice, PChar(pc)^, 100, dwread, nil);


for n:=0 to dwread div iBytesPerMFTRecord -1 do   // `EIntOverflow` exception
```

It seems that Readfile is returning something strange for `dwread` which triggers an
`EIntOverflow` exception on following line.

1°) What could be returned for `dwread` to trigger this exception ?

2°) How to control that ?

Comment: have you looked at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417919/delphi-how-to-avoid-eintoverflow-underflow-when-subtracting ?

Comment: Probably the  `ReadFile` function failed. You can verify this by looking at `GetLastError()` or `Win32Check()`

Comment: what type is n variable?

Comment: @Lieven That's incorrect. You check for failure by looking at the return value of `ReadFile`. Only if that returns false should you call `GetLastError`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - afaik, calling `GetLastError` after calling `readfile` always works as intented? My theory was that the `readfile` failed and left a 0 in `dwread` causing the `EINTOVERFLOW` on the next line.

Comment: @Lieven If `ReadFile` returns `TRUE` then you should not call `GetLastError` since its return is ill-defined. Only call `GetLastError` if the API docs explicitly say that you should.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I was under the assumption that `GetLastError` would simply return `ERROR_SUCCESS` if no error occured in `ReadFile` *(or any api that uses lasterror)*. The call would be redundant in case of success but it would never return an error code when `ReadFile` *(or again any api)* was successfull. If I'm mistaken, I definitely learned something (again:).

Comment: @Lieven It's a very very common mis-understanding. Many API calls to indeed reset the last error status to 0 in case of success. But plenty of them do not also. In which case you get a stale value when you call `GetLastError` and so much confusion ensues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero I guess:

```
{$Q+}
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  dw: Cardinal;
  I: Integer;

begin
  dw:= 0;
  I:= dw - 1;   // raised exception class EIntOverflow with message 'Integer overflow'.
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

from the delphi help  - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EIntOverflow

```
EIntOverflow is the exception class for integer calculations whose 
results are too large to fit in the allocated register.

EIntOverflow occurs when data is lost because an integer result 
is too large to retain.
```

so you need to change the data type of your variables used in the loop to accept larger values.